# How do I display an alternate timezone in a zsh prompt?

Tags: timezone, zsh, prompt

I would like my zsh prompt to display the time from two time zones, specifically the local time and UTC.  If I'm on PDT a display like this:

[22:21:59] [15:21:59] %

(I work with log files. Some are in UTC and others in local time)

If it helps, my bash prompt is:

`PS1="[\$(env TZ=UTC date +%H:%M:%S)] [\$(env TZ=America/Los_Angeles date +%H:%M:%S)] $ "`

Comment: You don't need `env`. Simply writing `$(TZ=... date ...)` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to work:

```bash
setopt promptsubst
zmodload zsh/datetime
PROMPT='[$(TZ=UTC strftime %T)][$(TZ=America/Los_Angeles strftime %T)] %% '
```

With the `zsh/datetime` [module](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fdatetime-Module-1) loaded, this should not require launching any sub-processes (unlike your `bash` example).

If you can use the current machine timezone, the prompt can be a bit shorter:

```bash
PROMPT='[$(TZ=UTC strftime %T)][%*] %% '
```

Comment: Thanks.   I was missing `setopt promptsubst`